# Auto generate email based on a field in SQL Server database

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, windows-services

I need something that will run on our internal network and monitor a SQL Server database for a condition based on a date field and then generate an email when that condition is met to an internal user.

Attempt to restate; It should monitor the DB and when the Date in a certain field reaches a variable it should generate and send an Email to the related User.

**i.e.** an *Auto-Reminder*

I send emails through our Exchange Server in our Desktop app already so I believe I am good on the Email portion. I have not done much web developing though so I am wondering if a Web Service is what I am looking for in answer to my question.

I once wrote a Windows Service that monitors a network location and generates an email based on events there, is this similar? How do you interact with a SQL Server database from a windows service? What about WCF, where does that fit in.

I just want to make sure I am looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same and a Windows Service is far better that a web service in your specific case.

You cannot automatically monitor something using a Web service; you must have another process (usually a Windows Service) that will query the webservice to trigger it's execution.

by the way, since you are monitoring a Database, you could also send email from a [SQL server trigger](http://blog.netnerds.net/2008/02/create-a-basic-sql-server-2005-trigger-to-send-e-mail-alerts/), but since you are doing in on a condition based on a date field, it's not really a good approach.

Comment: I see, Do I have to use something along the lines of O-SQL with a windows service in order to interact with the DB?  Thanks

Comment: I would not use OSQL, With dot net, it'S easy to connect to a database and query it.

Comment: here an example http://blog.netnerds.net/2008/02/create-a-basic-sql-server-2005-trigger-to-send-e-mail-alerts/

Comment: Thank you, I will look at the Windows Service some more then.  As noted in my comment to "Afshin Gh", I do not believe a Trigger will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to monitor one or more tables in a MS SQL Database, i think using **triggers** or **sql jobs** are the way you should go. (*I personally have no experience with triggers, but I think they are like events for tables*).

*But in another solution:*

You can develop a **windows service**. Put a **timer** in your windows service (let's say it elapses every 1 minute) and check what ever you need **when timer is elapsed** and than wait for the next event.

In this case you can check so many other conditions like: Pinging an IP, Run a query on a DB, check a file, etc...

**Web Services** are different things and they are not what you need right now. A web services is like a gateway or **api** for an application. When you use facebook's API, in fact you are connecting to a web service.

***UPDATE:***

About **WCF**: Let's say WCF is more cooler way of implementing a web service. It gives your more power, **not only when developing a web services**. You may want your application to communicate with other apps by a **TCP Channel**. Also it's kind of a successor to .Net remoting.

WCF on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

Comment: You are right, I did not think about "sql jobs", that a good idea!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I do not think I can use Triggers because I need to monitor a date field and compare it to todays date minus a set amount of days.  I don't think there would be anything to "trigger" from as the data will have been entered 6-12 months prior.

Comment: @Dav I think jobs are more reliable and I prefer them personally in many conditions. Usually when i need some scheduled task to run (like copying data from one DB to another every 10 mins), I use sql jobs.